# what is the difference between df['id'].duplicated() and df[df.duplicated('id')]

Tags: python, pandas

What is the difference between `df['id'].duplicated()` and `df[df.duplicated('id')]`?

Do they print same contents?

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: i couldnt figure the meaning between them..
but i got it now~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they won't.

`df['id'].duplicated()` returns a Series of booleans depending on whether the IDs are duplicated.

`df[df.duplicated('id')]` returns a filtered DataFrame where only the rows are kept in which the IDs are duplicated.

Example:

```
df
  id  col
0  A    0
1  A    1
2  B    2
3  C    3
4  C    4
5  C    5

df['id'].duplicated()
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True

df[df.duplicated('id')]
Name: id, dtype: bool
  id  col
1  A    1
4  C    4
5  C    5
```